# How to rethrow an exception to a generator

Tags: python, exception, generator

It seems that calling throw on a generator takes a type of an exception. How should I rethrow an instance of an exception (that I've already caught)?

EDIT:
Consider

```
def g():
    try:
        yield 1
    except Exception as e:
        yield 2

def f():
   x = g()
   print x.next()
   print x.throw(Exception)
```

But how can I throw an instance of an exception that already exists?

Comment: Could you please explain your question in more detail? Show some code maybe? It's not very clear at the moment.

Comment: Python doesn't have a `catch`.

Comment: Oh yeah.... That's embarrassing. I fixed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments to `generator.throw(...)` exactly mirror the arguments to the `raise` statement.  So it doesn't *have* to be an exception class; it can be an exception object, just like with `raise`.

This works perfectly fine:

```
x.throw(Exception("i'm an argument"))
```

The documentation is, admittedly, extremely misleading on this.  [The PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) at least gives you a hint:

> The effect of raising the exception is exactly as if the statement:
>
> ```
> raise type, value, traceback
> ```
>
> was executed at the suspension point.

Comment: I tried and saw it worked ... I just didn't know if that was defined to work, according to the standard

Comment: Over 3 years later and the docs are STILL misleading on this point! Thanks for this answer.